# ng-annotate with module constructor

Tags: angularjs, dependency-management, ng-annotate

Is it possible to use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) with angular module construction?

For example,

```
angular.module("testApp", ["ui.router"])
    .controller("FrontController", function($scope, $window, $log) {
       ...
    });
```

gets annotated with the various dependencies.  However, I've not been able to get the same to work with module instanciation, because removing the `["ui.router"]` array changes the module constructor to a module getter.

Furthermore, there is no documentation on this particular topic that I've been able to find.